# How display values on Y in ascending order, but save their index. Matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib

There are 2 arrays x - is in ascending order, y - chaotic. How display Y in ascendung order, but **save (x,y)**

[Now graphic looks like that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IuJR6.png)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x=[]
with open('D:\Programming\Contest\stepperf.txt','r') as a:
    for line in a:
        x.append(line.strip())
x =np.array(x)
y=[]
with open('D:\Programming\Contest\Hall.txt','r') as b:
    for line in b:
        y.append(line.strip())
y  = np.array(y)


fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 6))
plt.grid()     
plt.plot(x,y) 

plt.show()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dictionary Iterating -- for dict vs for dict.items()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24746712/dictionary-iterating-for-dict-vs-for-dict-items)

Comment: You really need to convert the values from string to numeric before appending them to the lists. E.g. `x.append(int(line.strip()))`

Comment: As far as I understand the question, the y values should be plotted in ascending order, totally ignoring their x value. My understanding might be wrong, but if that was the case you could achieve that by using the sorted lists as can be seen in @itaishz answer and then add the following:
    ax.set_xticks(np.arange(len(x_sorted)))
    ax.set_xticklabels(x_sorted)
    plt.plot(np.arange(len(y_sorted)), y_sorted)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) is a great way to keep arrays as a table, and has an elegant solution for your problem:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': x, 'y': y})
```

We stored your `x` and `y` into a DataFrame, `df`, with two columns - `x` and `y`.
Two options to access the data:

1. `df['x']` and `df['y']` are Pandas' series objects.
2. `df['x'].values` and `df['y'].values` are back to numpy arrays.

Sorting it, using [sort_values](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html):

```
df_sorted_by_y = df.sort_values(by='y', ascending=True)
```

Return to numpy arrays:

```
x_sorted = df_sorted_by_y['x'].values
y_sorted = df_sorted_by_y['y'].values
```

Edit:
In the last code blocked changed `df` into `df_sorted_by_y`

Comment: Note that with the values read as strings from file, they will stay of type string and will get sorted weirdly, e.g. `100` coming before `11`.  3-digit strings will be sorted as expected, but not so when different length numbers are mixed.

Comment: @JohanC True, did not notice OP doesn't convert them to int/floats. To add to the answer, this can be fixed through Pandas using `df['x'] = df['x'].astype(float)`.

Comment: Yes,saw your comment,fixed it. Thanks)